# modulus and argument of $(-4\sqrt{3}-4i)^3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Any fast method to obtain the modulus and argument of $(-4\sqrt{3}-4i)^3$?

If i use the exponential form to solve it, is it good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Notice, when $z\in\mathbb{C}$:
>
> - $$z=|z|e^{\arg(z)i}$$
> - $$\left|z\right|=\left|\Re[z]+\Im[z]i\right|=\sqrt{\Re^2[z]+\Im^2[z]}$$
>
> When $\Re[z]<0$ and $\Im[z]<0$:
>
> - $$\arg\left(z\right)=\pi+\arctan\left(\frac{\Im[z]}{\Re[z]}\right)$$

Now, when we have:

$$z^3=\left(|z|e^{\arg(z)i}\right)^3=|z|^3e^{3\arg(z)i}$$

---

So, you got:

- $$|z|^3=\left(\sqrt{\left(-4\sqrt{3}\right)^2+\left(-4\right)^2}\right)^3=8^3=512$$
- $$3\arg\left(z\right)=3\pi+3\arctan\left(\frac{-4}{-4\sqrt{3}}\right)=-\frac{\pi}{2}$$

So, now you can conclude:

$$z^3=\left(-4\sqrt{3}-4i\right)^3=-512i$$

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: write $-4\sqrt{3}-4i = -8\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}i\right)=-8\left(\cos \frac{\pi}{6}+i\sin \frac{\pi}{6}\right)$, and proceed to finish it with DeMoivre's formula...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the exponential form is the good way. Write it as:
$$
(-4\sqrt{3}-4)^3=\left[-4(\sqrt{3}+i) \right]^3=\left[-4(2e^{i\pi/6}) \right]^3=\left(-8e^{i\pi/6}\right)^3
$$